# How to disable one option from drop down select?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in WordPress which has multiple options in the `select`.

How do I disable one option so it is not selectable?

Answer (score 1):

You able to use a `disabled` attribute:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => select.options[0].disabled = true);
```

```html
<select id='select'>
  <option>Something #1</option>
  <option disabled>Something #2</option>
  <option>Something #3</option>
  <option>Something #4</option>
  <option disabled>Something #5</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Disable #1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select option:contains('NonSelectableValue')").attr("disabled","disabled");
```